# fixed header with responsive design

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to learn a tutorial from the net, but I basically did everything it says but for some reason the menu is not showing up while the screen goes small.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>New Header Design</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

body{

margin :0;
padding: 0;
font-family: sans-serif;


}

header{

    background :#00795f;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul {

background-color :#43a286;
overflow :hidden;
color: white;
padding : 0;
text-align: center;
margin:0;
-webkit-transition : max-height 0.4s;
-ms-transition : max-height 0.4s;
-moz-transition : max-height 0.4s;
-o-transition : max-height 0.4s;
-webkit-transition : max-height 0.4s;
}
nav ul li {

    display: inline-block;
    padding :20px;
}

nav ul li:hover{

    background-color:#399077;
}
a{

    text-decoration: none;
    color:inherit;
}
section{

    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 580px){

    nav ul{
        max-height:0;
    }
    .showing {
        max-height: 20em;
    }

    nav ul li{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width:100%;
        padding:15px;
        text-align: left;

    }
    .handle{
        display:block;
    }

}
.handle{

    width:100%;
    background:#005c48;
    text-align : left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color: white;
    display: none;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Website Created</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>   
        <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>HOME</a></li>
            <a href="#"><li>ABOUT</a></li>
            <a href="#"><li>BLOG</a></li>
            <a href="#"><li>SHOP</a></li>
            <a href="#"><li>CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class ="handle"> <h1>Menu</h1></div>


    </nav>
    <section>
        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.

    </section>
    <script>
$('.handle').on('click', function(){

    $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
});
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

So I am guessing that the jquery might not be right or there has to be some errors with classes while shrinking it down to mobile view. 
Need some help thanks.

Comment: A jsfiddle would be helpful. Apparently, the menu will be hidden if the screen becomes < 580px. You then have to click the menu link to make it visible again. What exactly is not working?

Comment: in my web browser the MENU is not showing, up so there is no where to click :S

Comment: i did try js fiddle its the same case, the menu is not showing whne the screen goes small .

Comment: what i meant was sharing a jsfiddle would be helpful. But never mind, since henrik123 was able to answer your question without one (please accept his answer).

Answer (score 2):

This is because the handle-class

```
.handle{
 width:100%;
 background:#005c48;
 text-align : left;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 15px 10px;
 cursor:pointer;
 color: white;
 display: none;
}
```

is called after the media query. Move the handle-class before the media-query like this and it will work.

```
.handle{

width:100%;
background:#005c48;
text-align : left;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 15px 10px;
cursor:pointer;
color: white;
display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 580px){

nav ul{
    max-height:0;
}
.showing {
    max-height: 20em;
}

nav ul li{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:100%;
    padding:15px;
    text-align: left;

}
.handle{
    display:block;
}

}
```